# Makefile: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to compile the whole folder with gcc.

Made some makefile (partially copied from different sources).

So I have my project root directory and I need to compile all the C files inside root dir.
Makefile configuration:

```
all: server

CC = gcc
LDFLAGS = -lmysqlclient -lwebsockets
CFLAGS= -Wall -g

src = $(wildcard *.c)
obj = $(src:.c=.o)

server: $(obj)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f build/server
    rm -rf build/server.dSYM
```

The error is:

`Makefile:11: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please find a way to make all the tabulators (in contrast to mutliple blanks) visible.

Comment: You're doing 2 things wrong: using spaces instead of tabs for the commands, and not googling the error message before posting a question to Stack Overflow :D

Comment: you use autoconf?

Comment: Yeah... I had whitespaces...